# Can Android Studio be configured to give suggestions for deprecated methods?

Tags: android, android-studio, ide, deprecation-warning

Just as android studio can give suggestions for imports can it be configured to give suggestions for deprecated imports?

[image]

Comment: you want to know what is replacement for deprecated method/Imports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only solution I can think of is to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> on the deprecated field (I suppose it will be <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> on Mac OS X, but you can always check out the default Intellij's [keymap](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf), just to make sure) and read the documentation on this field which will look like this:

[image]

Here you can read the possible replacements of deprecated field/method. Of course, it will work **only** if the documentation has the info about the replacements' list.